# Using esc_url() on a url more than once

Tags: escaping

If I have a front-end post form where a user enters a url, is it OK and recommended to use `esc_url()` twice - once for cleaning the input before using `update_post_meta` for database storage, and again on output.

```
// escape url before using update_post_meta
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'url', esc_url( $url ) );

// escape url on output
echo esc_url( get_post_meta( $post_id, 'url', true ) );
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's okay to use it more than once, but not encouraged. However, in your first example, you're saving the URL to the database. When you do that, or when using the URL in the `wp_remote_*` context, or a redirect, or any other non-display context, you should be using `esc_url_raw()` instead.

Also note that `get_post_meta` will return an array, unless the third argument `$single` is set to true. If you're dealing with a single key-value pair you'll want:

```
echo esc_url( get_post_meta( $post_id, 'url', true ) );
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, just looked at the esc_url_raw function and it uses esc_url but with the third parameter 'db', perfect for storing it in the database with update_post_meta. And yes, I forgot to add the true parameter at the end of the get_post_meta.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Wordpress codex, it appears it would be better to pass the first URL using [esc_url_raw](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url_raw)

> The esc_url_raw() function is similar to esc_url() (and actually uses it), but unlike esc_url() it does not replace entities for display. The resulting URL is safe to use in database queries, redirects and HTTP requests.

So, it should probably be written like this:

```
// escape url before using update_post_meta
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'url', esc_url_raw( $url ) );

// escape url on output
echo esc_url( get_post_meta( $post_id, 'url', true ) );
```

So, to recap, `esc_url_raw` for database storage, and `esc_url` for display.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to mention the possibility of **validating** the user input  before storing it and then **escape** it when you display it.

There's e.g. the [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) PHP function with the `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` flag.

There's also the [`wp_http_validate_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_http_validate_url/) function, that's applied for the `wp_safe_remote_{post,request,get}` calls, *to avoid redirection and request forgery attacks*, as mentioned in the inline docs.